# Why should I prevent direct access to PHP files that do not echo anything?

Tags: php, security

For an example if I have a mail script or a script that writes to a database -  scripts that do not echo anything important (other than a thank you, or an error message), but do a lot of important back-end work.

What could the possible security concerns from accessing them directly be?

Is it worth preventing direct access to such files?

They are receiving data using `$_POST`/`$_GET` sent trough contact forms and then either mailing it or writing it to a DB (in both cases after good validation).

Still, can the data that is being worked with there be accessed somehow (other than cracking my account and downloading them :)), since obviously opening such files in browser will not give any results to the attacker?

Comment: Are these scripts *ever* using `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SESSION`, or `$_COOKIE`?

Comment: @Chris Yes, they are. They are just not echoing any of it. They are either writing it to the DB or mailing it (in both cases after good validation).

Comment: @Husar: Is the purpose of those files to be directly requested?

Comment: @hakre They are accessed trough contact forms. The data from the forms is sent to them via $_POST or $_GET and they either mail it or write it to the DB (after validation). The mail script also has vars that contain username and password for the sptm mail server.

Comment: @Husar: Then the files need to be requested, you you can not generally block access to those. However you can put the configuration (SMTP username and password) into a file of it's own and into a private directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Server misconfiguration

The security risk is, in case the web server fails to execute the php file (because configuration was reset), it's source-code will be displayed inside the browser as plain text. And you probably want to prevent that.

### Wrong Context

Next to that scenario, another problem is, if the file actually does something with your database data for example, calling the file even w/o any direct output will have influence of indirect output. This is normally unwanted as well.

In your case it sends an email even, so direct requests can be used to send emails. That is probably unwanted as well.

Not to mention the risks this can have in getting your stuff penetrated. Not that this would be the only place where it is possible, but you should keep the surface small.

### Improved File-Handling

The best approach however is to store the applications code outside of the webroot, so that those files are never accessible by a direct HTTP request.

Comment: The chances of that are pretty slim. I'd say the bigger security risk is that the script actually *executes*, but in the wrong context. Also if the configuration is reset, wouldn't the restrictions also be gone? Doesn't make a lot of sense...

Comment: I don't think storing them outside of the webroot is posability on shared hosting... I could write some sort of authentication though, but than again, if such server fails do hapen it will useless to?

Comment: @Husar: That depends on your shared hoster. Nowadays this should be possible. Contact your hoster to find out more, ask for a private dir.

Comment: Application code SHOULD generally be in the web root, unless you are using proprietary software that you don't want viewed.  Its the CONFIGURATION files that should not be in the web root.

Comment: @Chris: Slim chances are chances and misconfiguration of a server can happen. It's bad I know, so the point is more of a reminder what can go wrong. I'll re-use your wording however to improve the answer.

Comment: @Husar, I'm sure most webhosts allow you to keep your files one level under the `public_html` or `www` folder.

Comment: @Jeremy Walton: For an application it's totally equal if the code is proprietary or not. I have problems to follow your argument so, why should only proprietary code not put into the webroot?

Comment: Because open source code is just that, you don't care if it "accidentally" gets shown to the user.  The logic of the code is free for all.  The code itself will not generally tell them, say, how to connect to your database.  That's what the configuration does.  But proprietary code on the other hand, may contain logic that you don't want other people to have.  Showing that code could be devastating.

Comment: @Jeremy Walton: Next to the fact that open source code can be proprietary as well, there is also FLOSS code that gets hacked but is not public. Anyway, the fundamental question is if you want to accidently show your code or not and that is not related to the type of licensing technically.

Comment: I didn't mention security, i mean logic.  Logic is far more important to the business model than security.  Just because someone could hack in, doesn't mean that they have access to the code base.  Even with something popular like SQL injection.  This only affects the database, and login.  Unless your software GIVES access to see the underlying code somewhere, you are pretty safe from someone taking your underlying architecture.  Even that can be tricky.  For proprietary software, this is WAY more tricky, because the hacker has no idea of the underlying database structure.

Answer (score 1):

Like Chris said, if the script accepts any `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE` parameters, there is the risk of someone being able to **easily** penetrate your server.

If the script actually performs any actions that might cause problems if run too often or too quickly (like a long-running mail script), you might be an easy target for a DOS attack.

Basically, if the script does anything with anything and should only be called from another script, prevent it from running under any other circumstance. Some OSS projects (Joomla, Wordpress, etc.) use a constant to verify that a file is actually being called from within the application. The constant won't exist if the script is called by a user directly from their browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still, could you elaborate a bit more, or share an article that explains what do you mean by "easily penetrate"?

Comment: It would really depend on how your script is actually coded. If you are never, ever trusting user input and are very picky about validating that input, then you don't need to worry overmuch about that avenue. But I'm not a hacker, so I could be missing something there. That said, I would never leave a piece of my site's infrastructure unsecured for any reason - why even take the chance when avoiding the vulnerability completely is so trivial?

Comment: I should add that my second point is almost as important - if the script actually performs any kind of action, consider what the effects might be if that action were performed 100 times per second.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But I have good validation set up. Also I don't think the  DOS you described is a treat. The script only receives data trough a contact form so even if they do spam it, it will have to be slow (since I have a honeypot field :))

Comment: So if I 'View Source' on your form page, then feed the URL there into my DOS generator, nothing bad would happen? You have more foresight and guile than someone who wants to hack your site? Sorry, but no matter what, there is no reason to leave something unsecured that could be better secured with minimal effort. A honeypot field is a good start, validating user input is another good start, and using form checksums is another good start. Why not secure the receiving page itself though? Saying that no one *should* be able to get there is the same as saying that someone *could* get there.

Comment: Yes, I defiantly will secure it then.

Answer (score 1):

You just don't know what the script will do when executed out of context, so first of all, it's a good thing to prevent that from happening. Preferable this is done by setting a variable (or rather a DEFINE) in you entry page and make all other files check if it is set.

Then, it's a good thing to put the other files in a separate directory, outside your document root. This will prevent the scripts from being downloaded. That *should* never happen, because they are usually parsed, but a single error might cause PHP to be disabled in which case, the php files are fed through Apache as if they are plain text files.

If people can view your code, they may find out about data structure, maybe passwords, and vulnerabilities in your code.

So, if possible, put your files outside your documents root. If you do that, you won't need to check for that define, but it won't hurt if you do.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend your scripts to be accessed directly, then yes you should probably prevent access. Whether or not they echo anything is beside the point. The bigger problem is that they may still accept input from a user in the form of a `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SESSION`, or `$_COOKIE`. This could lead to SQL injection amongst other concerns. Furthermore, without the guidance of the main frontend page, the backend scripts may not know how to properly do their job (certain vars may not be set, etc) so very odd behavior could result.

The best thing you could do is put the worrisome php files **outside** of the htdocs directory, and then use `require` to pull them in. Obviously you'd need to set up your paths.