# PHP security - password and credentials management?

Tags: php, security, encryption

After reading through an article on a site, I became really worried for my own server's security...

Inside a PHP file, which is later on included on all my main php pages that get showed to users, my username and password (used all over my website - server root, mysql root etc) are inserted in plain text... is there anything to worry about? can anyone read the php file (like download it and read it instead of having the server execute it)?

Is there any risk of having my username and password stolen? they are simple text fields giving values to variables.

If so, is there any solution that you would suggest? like a crypto engine? or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related/Possible Duplicate of: [Why should I prevent direct access to PHP files that do not echo anything?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563501/why-should-i-prevent-direct-access-to-php-files-that-do-not-echo-anything)

Comment: Keep those files outside public directory so that they never can be viewed from the web. Also make sure the permission are set properly so that nobody on the system can view files. Finally don't store login credentials on your server, but use openID instead. A very friendly openid library is LightOpenID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store your configuration file containing usernames and passwords outside of your publicly-accessible root folder.

For example, if your root folder is `/home/username/public_html/` then store the config file in `/home/username/`.

You can still include the config file in your PHP scripts running in `public_html` but should anything go awry (i.e. your web server starts printing PHP script contents rather than processing scripts) then your usernames and passwords should still be safe.

Comment: thank you, i will try this. also, what should i do to keep overhead down? like i have one page:foo.php which includes the mysql connection page:connect.php from system root, which then includes credentials.php from the 'credentials' folder? is that ok? like system resources-ok?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be; one file including another.

Comment: ok,thanks! I will implement it and hope it'll go well. The overhead I was talking about was the idea that on one request, 3 files are accessed. I read somewhere that bigger files are preferable over small multiple files on one user request. anyway, thanks for everything!

Comment: Multiple requests do have a larger overhead that requesting one big file, but the differences are absolutely minimal; we're talking thousands of a second, maybe less.

Answer (score 2):

1. Store the file outside the web root
2. Set up the proper file permissions, so the other users can't use it.