# download php with login details using wget

Tags: php, security

If I have a php file that contains my twitter access and consumer keys and secrets in plain text, isn't it possible that somebody can just download that php file using, for example, wget, read the file and then know my twitter login keys? How would I protect against this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, store these files off the document root, and two, no, if you server is setup properly clients can never get the source code of a PHP file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Noob alert. Could you please explain how to store the files off the document root and how to know if the server is set up properly or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582173/php-security-password-and-credentials-management

Comment: @user1210454, yea what he said

Comment: Thanks, I've now pored over that and a similar SO page about PHP vulnerabilities, but none of the answers actually say HOW to do that. To illustrate, i have a file "index.html" that posts user input to "doStuff.php". doStuff.php has the twitter credentials. Does it mean I should put doStuff.php outside of the document root? If so, how does index.html then post to it? I apologise for the extremely noobish nature of my questions.

Comment: @user1210454 The other SO post does explain it. `doStuff.php` should `require` a file that is stored off the document root, which contains your credentials. E.g. if your document root is `/var/www/mysite.com/public_html` then you should store important files in `/var/www/mysite.com`